# Get notified only when Platform Balance Updates in Stripe - WebHook

Tags: stripe-payments, webhooks

I need to get notified when the Balance Updates in my Stripe Platform Account. I currently use the below WebHook.

```
switch (event.type) {
    case 'balance.available':
        const paymentIntent = event.data.object;
        console.log(paymentIntent);
        transfer("acct_1Jc63wPhWrt3Vrlk");
        console.log('End');
        break;
}
```

**Question**

I am working with few Connected Express Accounts and I still get notified when the Balance Updates in Connected Accounts as well.

Exact Issue: I transfer money from my Platform Acc to Connected Express Acc. I do get 2 notifications at the moment

> 1st Notification: Deduction from Platform Acc Balance

> 2nd Notification: Addition to Connected Acc Balance

I want to skip the 2nd Notification and get only notified when an update happens to the Platform Acc balance.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 types of webhook endpoints at Stripe: Account webhooks and Connect webhooks.

Account webhooks send you any events that happen on your Stripe account.

Connect webhooks send you events for any events that happen on Connect accounts.

You should register an Account webhook endpoint and remove your Connect webhook endpoint in that case (or disable the `balance.available` event on your Connect webhook endpoint).

Comment: Thank you. I tried to search for 2 types in Stripe documentation. But I couldn't find it. Could you please send me the documentation or a resource link showing the 2 different webhook types? Thank you.

Comment: https://stripe.com/docs/connect/webhooks#connect-webhooks